# Re Arrangement position of String(sentence) without using split() method

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string like this str , we have to change its position like str2 without using split() method , Is it possible to code in python .

str = "This is stackoverflow "
I need like this , str2 = " is this stackoverflow"

Comment: Strings are immutable in python, whatever you'll do the string won't change but rather a new string will be created.

Comment: Swapping words without using split()? Any solution seems like some sort of implementation of breaking sentence into words which is the definition of split().